# java Selenium Chrome - keyword searcher

Tags: java, selenium, keyword

I'm almost done creating a Supreme Bot. Now I need a keyword-searcher. They should search for a keyword on the page and then click on it.

For example:

> Illegal Business Hooded Sweatshirt Red

... the bot now searches for the keyword but also for the color. I uploaded a screenshot (from the Supreme page) and need your help.

Screenshot from the source code (Supreme):

[image]

My code I tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[text()='Illegal Business Hooded Sweatshirt']/p[text()='Red']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

p tage is not inside h1 tag and "red" is inside anchor tag a

So you can use this xpath:-  `//h1/a/[text()='Illegal Business Hooded Sweatshirt']/ancestor::div/p/a[text()='Red']`

Answer (score 0):

Since there're encoded symbols in between of text, I believe you can't find those items directly with xpath.

I suggest you to find all `<acticle>` tags, then for every `article` tag you search for `<h1>` inside, retrieve it's text (with filtering out those weird symbols), and compare the text you want with the text article tag actually has.

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt replace with this code: https://hastebin.com/robilugimi.swift

Comment: I'm not the java guy, but I assume you're doing it wrong - you should do something like `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//article"))` - you'll get an array of WebElements. On every item of that array, you should call `findElement(By.xpath(".//h1")` and replace it via regex for example: /\W+\ (everything except letters and numbers) with ''.